# How to remove padding from left&right side

Tags: css

Im trying to remove the padding from left&right side by following custom css but doenst work

```
#main.site-main,.container, .site-content{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0em;
}
```

Please advise how to solve this.
The website is [www.taro0329.com](http://www.taro0329.com)

Thank you

Comment: I have checked your site your I can't found padding https://prnt.sc/pbnc1g

Comment: Thank you for your support. So means I can not remove them? Im using Vantage template

Comment: can you share your link

Comment: I just want to remove the white blank on the left and right side

Comment: which one can you please share screen short

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pbnkrf

Comment: .full-container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}

Comment: Worked!! thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting up margin/padding.
Try setting up max-width of `full-container` a `<div>` next to `site-main`:

```
body.responsive.layout-full #page-wrapper .full-container {
    max-width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

You can change `max-width` to your desired percentage value.